# perform single touch on isActionMove()

Tags: java, android, andengine, sprite, onmousemove

how to perform single touch on isActionMove() because when i move finger on sprites it takes multipal touch events and update scores twice thrice

```
mHardware[active] = new Sprite(pX, pY, java, this.getVertexBufferObjectManager()) {

    @Override
    public boolean onAreaTouched(TouchEvent pSceneTouchEvent, float X, float Y) {
        if (pSceneTouchEvent.isActionMove()) {
            score++;
        }
    }
};
```

i cant use isActionDown because its a game like fruit ninja in which i need to move finger across screen 
now problem is score is sometimes increasse by 2 sometimes by 3 because when i move finger on sprite application notices several short movements in place of one

Comment: @Alexey give me some solution Alexey if u hav solution given by julien is not working properly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should use

```
private static boolean isFirstMove;
public boolean onAreaTouched(TouchEvent pSceneTouchEvent, float X, float Y) {
    if (pSceneTouchEvent.isActionDown()) {
       isFirstMove = true;
    }
    if (pSceneTouchEvent.isActionMove()) {
        if(isFirstMove) {
            score++;
            isFirstMove = false;
        }
    }
    if (pSceneTouchEvent.isActionUp()) {
        isFirstMove = false;
    }
});
```

Comment: thnx its working...but no tht much efficient means sometimes it fails pls tell me if is there any other solution

Comment: I made a "macbouf" game with AndEngine, but it is very old. But I have used this solution.
I also remember that AndEngine often detects two clicks rather than one.
If this is your problem I can be another solution.

Comment: thanx julien dumortier its working now fine sory it was my mistak ur code is perfect

Answer (score 0):

If you found some what above answer correct for you then I have some suggestion in this.
You have to implement both scene and area touch event for your game scene.

SceneTouch event method contains two events isActionDown() and isActionUp() like in the following code.

```
public void onSceneTouchEvent(...){
    if(pSceneTouchEvent.isActionDown()){
        isFirstTouch=true;
        return true;
    } else if(pSceneTouchEvent.isActionUp()){
        isFirstTouch=false;
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Area Touch method contains only single event isActionMove() like in the following code.

```
public void onAreaTouch(...){
    if(pSceneTouchEvent.isActionMove()){
       if(isFirstMove) {
           score++;
           isFirstMove = false;
        }
        return true;
    } 
    return false;
}
```

You have to follow above strategy because some time desire event not occur for your sprite so you don't get your desire result.

Answer (score 0):

solution given by julien dumortier is working perfectly

```
static boolean isFirstMove=true;

public boolean onAreaTouched(TouchEvent pSceneTouchEvent, float X, float Y) {

if (pSceneTouchEvent.isActionMove()) {
    if(isFirstMove) {
        score++;
        isFirstMove = false;
    }
}
```

});